# Why do Postgres enums take 4 bytes?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, enums

According to https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-enum.html

> An enum value occupies four bytes on disk.

This seems an odd choice. Of course enum labels are mapped to fixed-sized integers for speed, but why 4 bytes?

Most of the time, enums are used for just a handful of options; 1 byte would suffice.

It's understandable that the designers might want to cater for the occasional larger enum. What is the largest enum that's ever been seen in the wild? I can imagine one being used for e.g. country code. That's 249 last count; just a few more countries would overflow 1 byte. I can see the rationale for making it 2 bytes.

But why 4? Has anyone ever used a database enum with more than 65536 cases? Does Postgres even actually work with that many?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the hood, an enum value is a `real`, not an `integer`, and that's the reason why it occupies four bytes. See the system catalog:

```
\d pg_enum
              Table "pg_catalog.pg_enum"
    Column     │ Type │ Collation │ Nullable │ Default 
═══════════════╪══════╪═══════════╪══════════╪═════════
 oid           │ oid  │           │ not null │ 
 enumtypid     │ oid  │           │ not null │ 
 enumsortorder │ real │           │ not null │ 
 enumlabel     │ name │           │ not null │ 
Indexes:
    "pg_enum_oid_index" PRIMARY KEY, btree (oid)
    "pg_enum_typid_label_index" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (enumtypid, enumlabel)
    "pg_enum_typid_sortorder_index" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (enumtypid, enumsortorder)
```

`enumtypid` is the OID of the data type (from `pg_type`), `enumsortorder` is the actual value stored in the table and `enumlabel` is the label.

To understand why `real` is used, look at that example:

```
CREATE TYPE wealth AS ENUM ('poor', 'rich');

SELECT * FROM pg_enum WHERE enumtypid = 'wealth'::regtype;

  oid  │ enumtypid │ enumsortorder │ enumlabel 
═══════╪═══════════╪═══════════════╪═══════════
 35366 │     35364 │             1 │ poor
 35368 │     35364 │             2 │ rich
(2 rows)
```

So far, that is not very surprising.

```
ALTER TYPE wealth ADD VALUE 'billionaire';

SELECT * FROM pg_enum WHERE enumtypid = 'wealth'::regtype;

  oid  │ enumtypid │ enumsortorder │  enumlabel  
═══════╪═══════════╪═══════════════╪═════════════
 35366 │     35364 │             1 │ poor
 35368 │     35364 │             2 │ rich
 35370 │     35364 │             3 │ billionaire
(3 rows)
```

That's also pretty clear.

```
ALTER TYPE wealth ADD VALUE 'millionaire' BEFORE 'billionaire';

SELECT * FROM pg_enum WHERE enumtypid = 'wealth'::regtype;

  oid  │ enumtypid │ enumsortorder │  enumlabel  
═══════╪═══════════╪═══════════════╪═════════════
 35366 │     35364 │             1 │ poor
 35368 │     35364 │             2 │ rich
 35370 │     35364 │             3 │ billionaire
 35371 │     35364 │           2.5 │ millionaire
(4 rows)
```

Ah! Since `'millionaire' < 'billionaire'`, its sort order must be between `'rich'` and `'billionaire'`. With an `integer`, we would have to change the sort order of `'billionaire'` to 4 to make room for the new label. But that is impossible, because the internal value of 3 might already be stored in a table somewhere, and we certainly cannot go around rewriting all those tables.

The obvious answer is to use a floating point value, so that we can interpolate new values between existing ones.

We have to "waste" four bytes, because there is no shorter floating point data type. If you consider that every table row has an overhead of 23 bytes, and that much of the three bytes you would like to save might well be lost to padding caused by alignment requirements, you will see that the waste is not all that bad.